# XML Schema: using attribute definition in complexType

Tags: java, xml, xsd, sax, xml-validation

I have some problems with XML validation using SAX parser. Here is a simple XML Schema I made to present the problem:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="urn:test"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="urn:test">

    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="content" type="ContentType"
                    maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="ContentType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute ref="title" use="required" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string" />

</xs:schema>
```

And here is a pretty simple XML file which in my opinion should be valid with regards to my schema:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root xmlns="urn:test">
        <content title="Title">
            Content comes here...
        </content>
</root>
```

The interesting thing is that when I try to parse this XML file, I receive the following validation error:

```
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'title' is not allowed to appear in element 'content'.
```

But if I remove the *title* attribute of the *content* element from the XML file, I still receive validation errors:

```
cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'title' must appear on element 'content'.
```

I have no idea what the problem is. Of course, this is just a simple example presenting the problem. I would like to understand the cause of this behavior. Also, it would be nice to find a resolution. I am not sure whether my Java code doing the validation is important in this case, I will post it later if it is necessary.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global declaration of the `title` attribute puts that attribute in the target namespace `urn:test`. That also means that you must qualify the reference to the attribute, both in the schema and in the instance document. By default, unqualified attributes have no namespace.

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="urn:test"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns="urn:test" xmlns:test="urn:test" >
....    
<xs:complexType name="ContentType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute ref="test:title" use="required" />
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string" />
```

and

```
<root xmlns="urn:test" xmlns:test="urn:test" >
    <content test:title="Title">
        Content comes here...
    </content>
</root>
```

This whole thing is quite subtle and when I try to validate the original instance document in ecplise I get two very confusing errors:

1. The `title` attribute *cannot* appear on the content element. This refers to the unqualified use of the attribute, and
2. The `title` element *must* appear on the content element. This refers to the missing qualified `test:title` attribute.

Granted, the error message could use a bit more context information.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Thank you for the answer. I think I will just avoid global attribute type definitions when it is possible. Using fully qualified names to reference these definitions is not a problem in the XML Schema, but I wouldn't like to use attribute names with namespace descriptor in the XML data file.